# Convert XML to HTML using XSLT template

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Can someone help me to convert the following XML to HTML using XSLT templates.

XML format:

```
<content>
<para>Please click <link href="https://www.google.com">here</para> to navigate to Google search.
</content>
```

Expected HTML:

```
<p>Please click <a href="https://www.google.com">here</a> to navigate to Google search.</p>
```

I have tried with the following template, not sure how to proceed further.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="content/para"/><p>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actual Result:

```
<p>Please click</p>
```

Comment: On StackOverflow you are expected to try and code it yourself first, and to show what you have tried along with the error or issue you are having.

Comment: You've given us the requirements, but you haven't shown us what you've tried or where you're having problems. There's no actual question. It seems more like a ["Do you haz teh codez?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/13231) request.

Comment: Please read [**Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/290085)

Comment: What is the programming language that you want to use to convert this xml to html?

Comment: I'm using jaxp-api library(Java) to convert XML to HTML by using XSLT templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with an [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copying). This will copy everything (elements, attributes, text, comments, processing-instructions) as-is.

Add more specific templates to override processing by the identity transform or the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#built-in-rule).

Example...

**XML Input** (fixed to be well-formed)

```
<content>
    <para>Please click <link href="https://www.google.com">here</link> to navigate to Google search.</para>
</content>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/content">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="para">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="link">
    <a>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p>Please click <a href="https://www.google.com">here</a> to navigate to Google search.
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

It would also be a good idea to get a [good book on XSLT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470192747) and read through that first.